# Adding a new class in android project must import R.java file

Tags: android, importerror, r.java-file

I just added a new class to my Android project, and I have an error that says that I have to import R... I don't understand because R is not supposed to be imported... I don't know why it is not recognized in this class and it is recognized in the others ?

I had several packages of an existing project and I created a new package and created a new class in that extends Activity. I also added the activity in the Manifest. The class contains only the basic onCreate method and the problem is on the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_card)` that gives me the error

Comment: Are u using Eclipse? If so, please turn on the option "Build Automatically" and perform "Clean Project".

Comment: I already done that, it doesn't remove the error

Comment: Then if possible, would u mind to give some more details (like screenshot of your project structure, etc.) to help us find the problem?

Comment: Alternatively, you could try making a change in one of your layout files to force R.java to get regenerated.

Comment: @crazylpfan I changed the name of an id and it didn't solve the problem. Does it mean R is not being regenerated ?

Comment: When I cahnged the name of the id it changed on the R.java file... But the error is still here

Comment: Now the error is "R cannot be resolved to a variable"... Is it the same error ?